# The smallest Android app in the world

Tags: discussion, policy, asking-questions

I am interested in understanding what is the smallest Android app possible that the OS will allow to be installed.  It need not have any function or interface (or even any executable code) - it just needs to be recognized by Android's package manager.

Would that be an appropriate question to ask here, or would StackOverflow be more appropriate?

Comment: this sounds fun!

Comment: Note that this site is for *challenges* rather than questions; perhaps it's best to post your idea to the [Sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) first, to make sure it fits the format.

Comment: @sanchises I'd say this idea would fit under the [tips](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/tips/info) tag, which is explicitly for questions rather than challenges.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG Meta!

Comment: @EriktheGolfer Thanks Erik!  Friendly group here!

Comment: Here is it: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aiuspaktyn.s

Comment: @Aiuspaktyn Thanks! Can you post the source code on Github?

Comment: Note: my own published small-ish (8.4k) apk: [redscreen](https://f-droid.org/packages/org.vi_server.red_screen/).

Answer (score 20):

## Yes, this is on-topic

*“How do I golf this?”* questions are welcome here, and this is essentially one of them: the OP wants to golf the smallest .apk file that Android’s package manager recognizes. If they supply some more specifics about their requirements (e.g. which Android device?) so others can help out, this is suited for the main site.